# Add Vuetify to a single .vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I've been struggling with adding Vuetify to a single component.

this will add the css:

```
<style scoped lang="scss" src="../../../../../../../node_modules/vuetify/dist/vuetify.css"></style>
```

But complex components like data tables results in errors.

Would really appreciate some help.
Thanks!

Comment: try to use @import ?

Comment: Why do you want to include it this way? Take a look at quick start https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start/

Comment: @kadash
The project is already built with Metronic, so adding Vuetify globally causes problems.

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I am having the same issues.

Comment: no solution yet, sorry. @m0bbin